# Return static fixed size array from a function

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it possible to return a static fixed size array from a function? What would be the syntax for this. I am not asking for `std::array`, neither for `T*`, I am specifically asking for arrays of the form `T arr[N]`. For instance one can take such an array as an argument in a function through the following syntax:

```
template<typename T, auto N>
void func(T (&arr)[N])
{

}
```

Comment: Not entirely certain what you are asking, but If the array is scoped within the function, as in `void func() { T arr[N]; }`, it is dead at the end of the function.

Comment: @user4581301 I want to treat it like an object and return a copy (possibly with copy elision). Is this infeasible?

Comment: You return the array, it decays to a pointer and expires. Pretty much the only way to get one out is to wrap it in a a class, and if you're going to do that, ta-dah, poor-man's `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function cannot return an array by value. You have observed that a function can take an array as an argument *by reference*; similarly a function can return an array *by reference*. To do so, it would be easiest to use the trailing return type syntax:

```
auto func() -> T (&)[N];
```

But arrays can be neither passed nor returned by value.

Comment: This answers my question more than adequately. What is the reason as to why  `T(&)[N]` cannot be at the place of the return type directly and but auto is necessary 
 (I tried it, it didn't work)?

Comment: @lightxbulb It can be done, but most people get the syntax wrong. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce8c356e17c9a2f4